# Facing issue on adding Parallelism feature in an Avroconvertor application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, parallel-processing, avro

I have an application which is used to take zip file and convert the text file under the zip files into avro files.

It executes the process in a serial manner in following way:

1) Picks the zip file and unzip it
2) Take each text file under that zip file and its content
3) Take avsc files(Schema files) from different location
4) Merge the text file content with the respective schema and hence making an avro file

But this process is done in serial manner(one file at a time).

Now I want execute this process in parallel. I have all the zip files under a folder.

```
folder/  
A.zip  
B.zip  
C.zip
```

1) Under each zip file there are text files which only consist of data (without Schema/headers)

My text file looks like this:

```
ABC  1234
XYZ  2345
EFG  3456
PQR  4567
```

2) Secondly I have a avsc files which has the schema for the same text files

My avsc File looks like

```
{
"Name": String,
"Employee Id" : Int
}
```

As an experiment I used

```
SparkContext.parallelize(Folder having all the zip files).map {each file => //code of avro conversion}
```

but in the code of avro conversion part(**which is under SparkContext.parallelize**) I have used **SparkContext.newHadoopAPIFile** feature of spark which also returns an **RDD**

So when I run application with these changes I get Task not Serializable issue.

Suspecting this issue because of two reasons
1) Have used SparkContext under SparkContext.parallelize
2) Have made an RDD inside an RDD.

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Now I need to have the **Parallelism feature** but not sure if there is any **alternative approach to achieve parallelism for this Use Case** OR **how to resolve this Task not Serializable issue**.

I am using Spark 1.6 and Scala Version 2.10.5